# Having some trouble with Jquery unbinding

Tags: jquery, click, unbind

Hey everyone, I have the smoothscroller script implemented in a sitewide include file. But I want to DISABLE it on the homepage.  (Smoothscroller basically uses the # anchors to make the browser scroll slowly and smoothly down to the anchor section. No jumping.)

Here is the kicker. I do not want to disable ALL clicks, ONLY the one regarding smoothscroller.

The smoothscroller code starts out like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
```

Now, I have TRIED putting the following after the smoothscroller call on the page:

```
$('a[href*=#]').unbind('click');
```

But this disables ALL the clicks on that link.  (They are using a jquery tab system that uses a click action as well.

I have also tried assigning a variable to the click function:

```
var narf = $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
```

And then used this unbind...

```
$('a[href*=#]').unbind('click',narf);
```

But it seemed to have NO effect! Can anyone shed some light on this? What obvious mistake am I missing?

Comment: If you want to differentiate from it, you'll need to bind smoothscoller with a some kind of indentifier instead (using a class or `rel=""` come to mind) . I'm sure there is an option for it when initializing the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use event namespacing:

http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

This will allow you to select a spcific event handler to unbind, like so...

```
$('a[href*=#]').bind('click.thisone', function(){
    // Wacky stuff happens
}).bind('click.thistwo', function(){
    // Crazy stuff happens
}).bind('click.thisthree', function(){
    // Weird stuff happens
});

// Only one is unbound
$('a[href*=#]').unbind('click.thisone');
```

Comment: @Sime - Why could instead of should? Is there another way?

Comment: @Jared "should" represents a mandatory obligation, "could" is used to suggest something. "could" is more appropriate here.

Comment: @Jared Alternative solution is here: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events (third code block)

Comment: @Sime - To accomplish the task requested, the OP "should use namespaces". That is entirely appropriate...

Comment: @Sime - I see. I still think they should use namespacing... :P My personal opinion. ;)

Comment: @Jared No, the OP is not obligated to use namespaced events to accomplish the requested task - there *are* alternative solutions. So, by definition, "should" is not the correct verb.

Comment: That's the stuff Sime! Worked absolutely perfectly.  Namespaced events, going to have to remember that.